# Getting: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError, can't find main method

Tags: java, spring, docker, maven

I'm trying to create a docker container from "apka:apka" image using Dockerfile file in docker-compose.yml. Created container does not run in docker desktop beacuse I'm getting:

```
21:42 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication
at ZadanieRekrutacyjne.ZadanieRekrutacyjne.ZadanieRekrutacyjneApplication.main(ZadanieRekrutacyjneApplication.java:16)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
 1 more
```

What is th problem? I've read that it may be caused by spring boot verion not being compatibile with sone dependencies but I tried to change versions and it did nothing. Why it doesn't work?

ps. for some reason I had to manually add MANIFEST-INF directory with MANIFEST.FM file in it to the resource directory.

pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>ZadanieRekrutacyjne</groupId>
    <artifactId>ZadanieRekrutacyjne</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ZadanieRekrutacyjne</name>
    <description>Plants</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.26</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4</version>        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.32</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>3.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <configuration>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>
                                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                                    </exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

</project>
```

dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:17
ADD target/ZadanieRekrutacyjne-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar ZadanieRekrutacyjne-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
CMD ["java", "-jar", "/ZadanieRekrutacyjne-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  sql-test:
    container_name: sql-test
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: zadanierekrutacyjne
      MYSQL_USER: recruit
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: recruit
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: Krzysiek123qweasd,./
    volumes:
      - "./sql-test:/data/mysqldb"
    expose:
      - "3306"
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    #    command: -p 3306
    restart: always


  apka:
    container_name: apka
    image: apka:apka
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      - spring.profiles.active=
    depends_on:
      - sql-test
```

main class

```
package ZadanieRekrutacyjne.ZadanieRekrutacyjne;

import ZadanieRekrutacyjne.ZadanieRekrutacyjne.Security.Security;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan("ZadanieRekrutacyjne.ZadanieRekrutacyjne.Entity")
@EnableJpaRepositories("ZadanieRekrutacyjne.ZadanieRekrutacyjne.Repositories")
@Import(Security.class)
public class ZadanieRekrutacyjneApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ZadanieRekrutacyjneApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

manifest.fm

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Build-Jdk: 17.0.5
Main-Class: ZadanieRekrutacyjne.ZadanieRekrutacyjne.ZadanieRekrutacyjneApplication
```

application.properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
#spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/zadanierekrutacyjne
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://host.docker.internal:3307/zadanierekrutacyjne?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false
spring.datasource.username=recruit
spring.datasource.password=recruit
#spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

path to class with main method:
ZadanieRekrutacyjne.ZadanieRekrutacyjne.ZadanieRekrutacyjneApplication

Comment: it fails to execute `SpringApplication.run(...)` because there's probably no spring boot in your jar. How did you build the jar? https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.1.x/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#packaging docs have some bits about `repackage` in there that may be needed. Would Ideally start out with a sample generated by https://start.spring.io/ - those samples have the right setup to generate a working jar if you select jar packaging. For docker there's also https://spring.io/guides/topicals/spring-boot-docker/ - if it works you don't have add files yourself as well

Comment: Also, using the parent `2.6.2` would try to include spring-boot 2.6.2, if you combine that with dependencies from 3.x manually (the parent contains all the recommended versions) that might not work. See generated samples, they only version it contains is the version of the parent, the rest needs no explicit version (unless you really want to use something not recommended by the parent pom)

Comment: It was a project created in spring.io. I don't know much about jar building I just followed a tutorial that told me to use "install" option in maven, I did and .jar file was created in target